# Table problems with WebKit

Tags: css, webkit, html-table

I'm having trouble getting this code to show up correctly in WebKit browsers(chrome/safari). It looks fine in IE6, IE7, and FireFox.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/company/a_cherry_on_top/line/gift_cards/?v=s2"><img src="/i/thumbnails/acotgc25sm.gif" alt="Gift Certificate"/></a>
        </td>

        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/article?a=2044" target="_top">Wishlist</a>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/article?a=2125" target="_top">Link to Us</a>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://www.shareasale.com/shareasale.cfm?merchantID=8362" target="_blank">Affiliate Program</a>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/article?a=1521" target="_top">Privacy</a>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/article?a=1395" target="_top">Guarantee</a>
        </td>

        <td rowspan="2" style="width:160px;">
            <script src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/translatemypage.xml&up_source_language=en&w=160&h=60&title=&border=&output=js"></script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/article?a=3069" target="_top">About Us</a>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/article?a=1467" target="_top">Shipping</a>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/article?a=12342383" target="_top">Why Buy From Us</a>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/article?a=1397" target="_top">Contact Us</a>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle;">
            <a href="http://{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/help" target="_top">Help</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that WebKit makes the top row very small and the bottom row fill in the rest of the space instead of each row having an equal height.

Anyone have any ideas of how to make it show up how I want it to in WebKit based browsers?

Comment: Pasting that code into Safari and Chrome works fine for me.

It would be helpful to see the actual HTML generated by Smarty.  

And even more helpful to see a live example or at least all of the HTML generated.

Comment: Have you validated the syntax at W3C yet?

Answer (score 1):

I have a few recommendations for you but I can't answer your question completely because WebKit seems to render your source fine when I try it.

1. First, maybe you can change `width="100%"` to `style="width:100%;"` Perhaps combined with the other markup, it's putting the browser in quirks mode.
2. Second, make sure you have the correct doctype on and your code validates or AT LEAST comes close. The doctype I used when copying & pasting your code was XHTML Strict.

Otherwise, please post the source code of the whole page or just link to a live demo. Even a screenshot would help.

Answer (score 0):

I could help more with a live example to test on but you could try adding this to your `tr` tags.

```
<tr style="height: 50%;">
```

Assuming you only need two rows this will bring them to equal height.

Answer (score 0):

a proper example to ensure it is not showing correctly in webkit is the following:

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" width="15">
        this is a very high rowspan 2 row that will thus be split over 2 rows, it prevents the second row from being formatted in height
      </td>
      <td>
        this should be big instead
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20">
      <td height="20">
        this row fails to size to 20 height on webkit
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see the left part is rendered fine, but the right part should be different, as in the top row should populate the left over space and the bottom row is set to 20 height (as you can see neither the tr height nor the td height is taken into consideration by webkit). this renders fine in all other browsers

EDIT:
after playing around and tinkering about my problem, I came to the below solution.
completely relying on jquery reading the height attribute property from the row you want to change:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pipnorowspan").height(function(){
    return $("#rcarowspan").height() - $("#piplowerrow").attr('height') + 2;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="200" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #000;" id="ertable">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="border:1px solid #000;">
      <td rowspan="3" width="15" id="rcarowspan" style="border:1px solid #000;">
        this is a very high rowspan 2 row that will thus be split over 2 rows, it prevents the second row from being formatted in height
      </td>
      <td id="pipnorowspan" style="border:1px solid #000;">
        this should be big instead
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="20" id="piplowerrow" style="border:1px solid #000;">
      <td height="20" style="border:1px solid #000;">
        this row fails to size to 20 height on webkit
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```